# Unfamiliar with Regex Match Symbols within Error Message

Tags: ruby, regex, rspec

I'm working on the following Ruby Challenge [GIST LINK](https://gist.github.com/olitreadwell/4772c6a12d0d8c73c15f)

#### My question is, HOW DO I READ THE PORTIONS OF MY ERROR MESSAGE(below) AFTER "got:" IN ORDER TO MAKE CHANGES TO MY REGEX OR #GSUB EXPRESSIONS?

### Exercise: Print out a times table

Implement a method called times_table which takes as its input an integer and prints out a times table with that number of rows.

The numbers can be separated by any spaces or tabs, but each row must be on a new line. This means it's ok if the columns don't line up.

For example, times_table(5) should print the following out to the screen:

```
1   2   3   4   5
2   4   6   8  10   
3   6   9  12  15   
4   8  12  16  20   
5  10  15  20  25
```

Again, you don't need to worry about the spacing between columns. The point of the exercise is to understand the logic, not master the formatting. You should be at least one space/tab between the numbers, though, otherwise it won't look like a times table!

*I have written the following code, which sufficiently prints out a times table, albeit not very prettily. I assume this would satisfy the conditions of the exercise.*

### MY CODE

```
def times_table(rows)
  return "Argument must be a positive integer" unless rows.is_a?(Integer) && rows > 0 
  array_of_arrays = []
  base_array = (1..rows).to_a

  counter = 1
  1.upto(rows){
    temp_array = base_array.map.with_index { |x,i| x *= counter}
        array_of_arrays << temp_array
        counter +=1     
    }

nested_array_string = array_of_arrays.to_s

nested_array_string.gsub!(/(\])/, "\n")
nested_array_string.gsub!(/(\[\[)|(, )/, " ")
nested_array_string.gsub!(/(\[)/, "")
nested_array_string.gsub!(/(^ )|(\n\z)/, "")
# nested_array_string.gsub!(/(\n\z)/, "")
end

puts times_table(1)
```

*However, once I submit the challenge I am receiving the following error messages.*

#### My question is, HOW DO I READ THE PORTIONS OF MY ERROR MESSAGE AFTER "got:" IN ORDER TO MAKE CHANGES TO MY REGEX OR #GSUB EXPRESSIONS?

I wasn't able to find an answer to what "@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@" represented. I'm assume (DANGER) the final "/ +" represents regex expressions matching one or more whitespaces within my string value.

### Error Messages

```
Error!
times_table correctly prints a 1x1 times table
expected: /1\s*$/ got: "" (using =~) Diff: @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@ -/1\s*$/ +""

Error!
times_table correctly prints a 5x5 times table
expected: /1[ \t]+2[ \t]+3[ \t]+4[ \t]+5\s*\n2[ \t]+4[ \t]+6[ \t]+8[ \t]+10\s*\n3[ \t]+6[ \t]+9[ \t]+12[ \t]+15\s*\n4[ \t]+8[ \t]+12[ \t]+16[ \t]+20\s*\n5[ \t]+10[ \t]+15[ \t]+20[ \t]+25\s*$/m got: "" (using =~) Diff: @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@ -/1[ \t]+2[ \t]+3[ \t]+4[ \t]+5\s*\n2[ \t]+4[ \t]+6[ \t]+8[ \t]+10\s*\n3[ \t]+6[ \t]+9[ \t]+12[ \t]+15\s*\n4[ \t]+8[ \t]+12[ \t]+16[ \t]+20\s*\n5[ \t]+10[ \t]+15[ \t]+20[ \t]+25\s*$/m +""
```

NOTE: This is my second StackOverflow question, so please let me know if there is more information or a better formatting that I can provide going forward. :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please avoid using all caps LIKE THIS, BECAUSE IT MAKES YOUR QUESTION HARD TO READ AND IT LOOKS LIKE YOU'RE YELLING! WHY ARE YOU YELLING AT US?!?!?!

Comment: Don't repeat the same question.

Comment: A better strategy would be simple debug techniques. I would suggest printing out `nested_array_string` before and after each of the regex's operating on it.

Comment: The way you're printing the table is overcomplicated.

Comment: @Cupcake my bad. Just trying to emphasize what I'm asking with so much data passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some techies talk in regex. Some specifications do too, like w3c XML specs.
Its a way to tell you what is acceptable format of the data they expect if it
were being parsed with regex.

In this case it looks like they are telling you what the form of the string passed
to thier validator did not match thier regex - the thing after ***expected***.

What they ***got*** I'm guessing, was the result of the match, i.e. `""`  ??

Don't know, but thats what it looks like to me.
So, guessing the string submitted did not match.
Did you add spaces between numbers and a newline at the end?

```
 expected: /1[ \t]+2[ \t]+3[ \t]+4[ \t]+5\s*\n2[ \t]+4[ \t]+6[ \t]+8[ \t]+10\s*\n3[ \t]+6[ \t]+9[ \t]+12[ \t]+15\s*\n4[ \t]+8[ \t]+12[ \t]+16[ \t]+20\s*\n5[ \t]+10[ \t]+15[ \t]+20[ \t]+25\s*$/m
 got: ""
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to look at it again.